# How to add a subscription filter using CloudFormation?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm generating a CloudFormation template with several AWS Lambda functions. As part of the CloudFormation template I also want to add a subscription filter so that CloudWatch logs will be sent to a different account. 
However, since I don't know the name of the logs groups at advance and couldn't find any way to have a reference to them I wasn't able to solve it.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function to get the log group name. For example:

```
"LogGroupName": {
    "Fn::Join": [
        "",
        [
            "/aws/lambda/",
            {
                "Ref": "MyLambdaFunction"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Note that `MyLambdaFunction` is the name of your Lambda function block in the CloudFormation template.

Comment: Thank you Praveen. This helped me but now I'm in the next step where during the creation of the stack I'm getting the error: The specified log group does not exist. (Service: AWSLogs; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException; Request ID: e4a3ffd1-0b19-4c83-b172-9f19737e2e8b)

Maybe the log is only created after the first invocation? Is there something we can do here?

Comment: You can create the log group in CloudFormation with the same name the Lambda function expects it to be. You can then depend on that log group resource for your subscription.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [custom function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) to invoke your lambda which in turn can run your lambda with a test payload or something like that, which eventually will create a log stream then you can refer to that log group for subscription as mentioned by praveen earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The way [Serverless](https://serverless.com/) does it should work for you. It creates a log group resource with a name matching what your Lambda function will use. You can then reference that log group wherever you need it. You will have to give your Lambda function a name and not use the default naming behavior. You can use the stack name to make it unique.

Something like:

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Resources": {
    "FunctionLogGroup": {
      "Type": "AWS::Logs::LogGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "LogGroupName": {
          "Fn::Sub": "/aws/lambda/MyFunction-${AWS::StackName}"
        }
      }
    },
    "MyFunctionNameRole": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties": {
        "ManagedPolicyArns": ["arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"],
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [{
            "Action": ["sts:AssumeRole"],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
              "Service": ["lambda.amazonaws.com"]
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    },
    "MyFunction": {
      "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
      "Properties": {
        "Code": {
          "ZipFile": "def index():\n  return 'hello world'\n"
        },
        "FunctionName": {
          "Fn::Sub": "MyFunction-${AWS::StackName}"
        },
        "Handler": "handler.index",
        "MemorySize": 128,
        "Role": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "MyFunctionNameRole",
            "Arn"
          ]
        },
        "Runtime": "python3.6"
      },
      "DependsOn": [
        "FunctionLogGroup"
      ]
    },
    "MySubscriptionFilter": {
      "Type" : "AWS::Logs::SubscriptionFilter",
      "Properties" : {
        "DestinationArn": "TODO TODO",
        "FilterPattern": "",
        "LogGroupName": {"Ref": "FunctionLogGroup"},
        "RoleArn": "TODO TODO"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks kichik. 
I've tried to follow your guidelines but when building the stack I'm getting this weird error from AWS:
nullnull (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 400; Error Code: null; Request ID: null)

when removing this line from the function defintion:
  "FunctionName": {
                    "Fn::Sub": "/aws/lambda/FunctionName-${AWS::StackName}"
                },

I was able to create the stack. Any thoughts?

Comment: seems like just using:
"FunctionName": { "Fn::Sub": "/FunctionName-${AWS::StackName}" }
Did the trick. 

Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah that's a typo. Function name shouldn't have `/aws/lambda`.